# Zend framework 2 sending email

Tags: php, email, zend-framework

I am sending emails to different users but its giving me this error, I don't know what that means

```
 $mail = new Message();
        $mail->setFrom('no-reply@example.com', "Example.com");
        $mail->setBody($htmlString);
        $mail->addTo("email@gmail.com", "User Name");
        $mail->setSubject("Subject");

        $transport = new Sendmail();
        $transport->send($mail);
```

and it giving the error

> File:
> /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:291
>
> Message:
> Unable to send mail: Unknown error

[image]

Comment: What's inside `error.log`? Have you defined mail transport type?

Comment: where to define that

Comment: Check manual: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mail.transport.html . For testing purposes it can be used `Zend\Mail\Transport\File`